# Can I get ~1cm accuracy with a 2.5m accuracy GPS module and RTCM/NTRIP data after post processing?

Tags: python, gps, accuracy

I'm a new on this, so I have a subscription to a RTK? service that sends correction data (RTCM/NTRIP) over GPRS/UMTS (you get a SIM card with the subscription)

I'm also having a Rover of around 2mx1.5m that navigates based on a Python script that runs on a Raspberry (Companion Computer) to which a Pixhawk (controller) is connected to control the whole rover and peripherals. The Pixhawk has a uBlox neo 6m GPS module connected to it (I read somewhere 2.5m accuracy?)

Is it somehow possible to get the correction signal from the SIM card subscription and combine it with the not so accurate GPS module to create a better accuracy signal after post-processing? What I then can inject into the Pixhawk controller? Is this even possible or should I get a RTK GPS module where I can inject the correction data into the GPS module (is this how it works?) (I assume the RTK GPS processes the data and spits out a cm level accurate position?)

I need better accuracy when the rover is driving over agriculture land and I'm already having the expensive RTK subscription so I better use it.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

uBlox Neo-6 can use real-time corrections to improve accuracy - technically, it will only use RTCM 2.3 message types 1, 2, 3, 9, which would usually be provided in an NTRIP stream which has a name containing "DGPS" or DGNSS".  You can read about the uBlox requirements in the [uBlox6 protocol specification](https://www.u-blox.com/en/ubx-viewer/view/u-blox6_ReceiverDescrProtSpec_(GPS.G6-SW-10018)_Public?url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.u-blox.com%2Fsites%2Fdefault%2Ffiles%2Fproducts%2Fdocuments%2Fu-blox6_ReceiverDescrProtSpec_%2528GPS.G6-SW-10018%2529_Public.pdf).  The uBlox u-Center application can be used to supply RTCM corrections to a uBlox receiver, but u-Center only runs on Windows.

A full-accuracy RTK stream is unlikely to contain these messages - professional users of NTRIP corrections usually want decimeter or centimeter accuracy, which requires a different set of messages, nowadays usually in RTCM3 format which Neo-6 will not understand - but NTRIP correction suppliers sometimes provide DGPS or DGNSS corrections for less demanding users.

From my experience with uBlox receivers in Trimble equipment, you could hope to get accuracy of around 1M to 2M but it's very dependent on the antenna which is used.

Note that the quoted accuracy for Neo-6 receiver has lots of conditions "*CEP, 50%, 24 hours static, -130dBm, SEP: <3.5m*", so don't rely to heavily on manufacturer specifications!

Comment: Thankyou for your explanation! I asked the company behind the RTK services and their NTRIP service, I have the possibility to choose from different RTCM versions.

Comment: And I need to connect to their NTRIP caster with an IP, username, password etc . Then they use a VRS to give correction data. (I also have to send my location in NMEA format over IP to their caster?) 
So I was looking into an NTRIP client and came across str2str which is a part from RTKlib. is it possible to run str2str on the Raspberry and connect to the NTRIP caster? Then receive the RTCM and send it out over serial to a suitable NEO

Comment: NTRIP software sometimes offers "single base" corrections (for those you choose the base which is closest to your location and you don't have to send location) as well as VRS (Virtual Reference Station) corrections where you send your location to the NTRIP server and the server sends custom corrections.  For the other question, RTKLib is commonly used but I have not used it myself - I suggest you post a new question about RTKLib on Raspberry Pi.

Comment: I will look more into RTKlib! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Actually if your are going to work close to any of these RIMS https://egnos-user-support.essp-sas.eu/new_egnos_ops/resources-tools/edas-dgnss-coverage-map you can expect good accuracy values since the uBlox Neo-6 supports SBAS / EGNOS. Click on the area where you will work to see the best accuracy you can get with DGNSS, you can also get better accuracy with SBAS than with GPS in any other areas just by using the EGNOS corrections obtained with your Neo-6. EGNOS is available for free in the EU. In any case you would need to create an EDAS Account to make use of this DGNSS service and configure it in your device, It works for us. The guys from their helpdesk assisted us to create an account and suggested info based on our particular use-case.

Comment: My experience with u-blox and SBAS corrections (WAAS in USA and the Aus/NZ test SBAS satellite in NZ) was that using SBAS didn't make a huge difference at improving the accuracy.  The horizontal error for features using an average of 25 positions decreased by maybe 20%.  Looking at a set of positions collected over a few hours, using SBAS definitely gave a tighter grouping / fewer outliers.